# Cannot work with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am wondering why there is not a determined way to work with `Jackson`. I just want to parse `JSON` string:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Customer[] myObjects = mapper.readValue(file, Customer[].class);
```

But I really confused what should I import to do that. According to this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/jackson/convert-java-object-to-from-json-using-jackson-example/), I tried to import `mapper-asl.jar`. But I get this compile error:

```
The type org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Then I try to import `jackson-core-2.4.2` and `jackson-databind-2.4.2`. So there was no compile error but I got this runtime exception instead (in mapper definition line):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
```

Guide me please what should I import to work with `Jackson`. Thanks

Comment: As others point out, you have some version mixup: `org.codehaus.jackson` is for Jackson 1.x, and `com.fasterxml.jackson` for 2.x. And something else you have is depending on Jackson 1.x (probably 1.9, Hadoop, DropWizard or Jersey maybe?)

Comment: No the problem is solved. Just I should add `jackson-annotation` library. Thanks.

Comment: Ok good, glad it got resolved!

Comment: After adding jackson-annotation, do we have to import any class file ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use these dependencies
[jackson-databind](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.4.1.3) 
[jackson-annotations](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.1)
[jackson-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.1.1)

```
public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String,String> dt=new Hashtable();
    dt.put("1", "welcome");
    dt.put("2", "bye");
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dt)
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    }    
}
```

Comment: It worked just after I added jackson-annotations. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've just added jackson-databind as maven dependency and my projects works. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Looks like mixed up references.

You might be using a library that uses an old version of Jackson itself (i.e. the `org.codehaus` package)...

I usually just reference Jackson through Maven.

Something like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```