# How to convert String to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, httprequest

I am using a `httprequest` to get Json from a web into a string.

It is probably quite simple, but I cannot seem to convert this string to a `javax.json.JsonObject`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, Clear the question. I did not get , What you want

Comment: Please clarify your question, Do you want to get the JSON object in java, if possible please provide a snapshot of what you want to do?

Comment: Simply as it says: a string containing a json string to a jsonObject from javax.json.jsonbuilder and nog org.json.JSONBuilder

Comment: Refer my answer from [String to Json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25947473/3496666)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader("{}"));
JsonObject object = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();
```

See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) and [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp003.htm).

Comment: it worked, but I had to import the Json Processing API Jar from https://jsonp.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 22):

Since the above reviewer didn't like my edits, here is something you can copy and paste into your own code:

```
private static JsonObject jsonFromString(String jsonObjectStr) {

    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonObjectStr));
    JsonObject object = jsonReader.readObject();
    jsonReader.close();

    return object;
}
```

Comment: it worked, but I had to import the Json Processing API :\

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an outdated question and that this answer would not be relevant years back, but still.
Using Jackson Library is the easiest technique to solve this problem.
Jackson library is an efficient and widely used Java library to map Java objects to JSON and vice-versa. The following statement converts JSON String representing a student into a Java class representing the student.

```
Student student = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Student.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Jackson to parse a string representation of a json object into a JsonNode object.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class J {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    var json =
        """
          {
            "candle": {
              "heat": 10,
              "color": "orange"
            },
            "water": {
              "heat": 1,
              "color": null
            }
          }
        """;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var node = mapper.readTree(json);
    System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was how to convert a string to a `javax.json.JsonObject`. I can't find such object in this answer.