# How to convert a String to a JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I am using a `HttpURLConnection` to get `Json` from a web into a string.

And i'm storing web string into `BufferedReader` and after that storing it in a new `String`.

And string is here:-

```
{"coord":{"lon":72.85,"lat":19.01},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.131,"pressure":1024.24,"humidity":84,"temp_min":302.131,"temp_max":302.131,"sea_level":1024.75,"grnd_level":1024.24},"wind":{"speed":4.77,"deg":302.001},"clouds":{"all":12},"dt":1459677392,"sys":{"message":0.0102,"country":"IN","sunrise":1459645229,"sunset":1459689786},"id":1275339,"name":"Mumbai","cod":200}
```

How can i convert it into JsonObject.

I've also seen this answer ([How to convert String to JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948000/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject)) but it's not working.

Here is code:-

```
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String localoutput;
    while ((localoutput = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
            output=localoutput+output;
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);  
    }

JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(output));
JsonObject object = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();

try {
    String cityname = object.getString("name");
    System.out.println(cityname);
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here output is the String which I've mentioned it earlier.
I'm not getting the Output Cityname in my console.

Comment: which libary are you using for json in java ?

Comment: Show us the code you tried

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  You have a dozen to choose from.  (And check the return code/error parm, then consult the documentation for your chosen parser to see with it might mean.)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Now you can see code here. @HotLicks

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library. It provides very simple API, to convert a String to json object simply do the following:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```